# Flex div горизонтальная прокрутка таблицы

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

В чем причина изменения левого div, когда вставляешь в правой большую таблицу с `overflow-x: auto;`.
[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/htuu1urz/4/)

Пробовал различные варианты, но все время мое левое меню будто сужается, когда в правом блоке много данных. Подскажите как реализовать такой просто шаблон (слева меню, в теле справа находится большая таблица, которая прокручивается по горизонтали).

Замечал, что если напрямую правому блоку div придать свойство: `overflow-x: auto;`, то все работает, однако мне нужно помещать блоки внутри этого блока, и потом все ломается.

P.S.: Как же ненавижу верстку((( Много всяких нюансов, компромиссов и багов. Почему еще не сделали адекватные способы веб-дизайна(( Занимаюсь бэкендом. Там все строго и "правильно работает".

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу блок слева должен быть фиксированной величины, тогда могу предложить использовать `min-width` и он будет необходимой вам величины. Если он должен быть динамически изменяемым, то там нужно будет сделать немного иначе, сделал под ваш вариант.

```css
.page-wrap {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

#nav {
    min-width: 300px;
    background: green;
}

#main {
    background: gray;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">

  <!-- Nav -->
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Main -->
  <section id="main">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
          <td>Column</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Интересно, как следовало бы поступить, если требуется изменяемый свой размер блок?
И вообще почему такое происходит сужение левого блока. Найти бы какую-нибудь литературу, чтобы разобраться в механизмах, которые на таких сайтах как W3С не описаны

Comment: Ну вообще, как вариант, вместо пикселей поставить проценты, но само понятие min и max width будут делать подстраиваемую верстку. Главное - указать границы, хотя бы минимальную, при которой происходит ненужные разрушения верстки)